# Place view on edge of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` that is a map showing locations inside a building. When the user selects a place, I show a popup pointing to the place on the map.

I move the view around with `leftMargin` and `topMargin`, but when the location is on the edge of the view, I want it to clip outside the `RelativeLayout` a bit.

I tried applying the solutions I found on here, namely setting this in the XML of the containing `RelativeLayout`:

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
```

But when I do that, the view still gets squished against the right edge of the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already move a view with margin values, you could simply use a FrameLayout, which does not do so much measurement stuff like a RelativeLayout.

If you are familiar with custom views, another solution would be using your own ViewGroup implementation, which takes care about the positions of its childs by View.layout(left,top,right,bottom).